# Not whole jsp is coming through ajaxc all in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, internet-explorer

I have created a div in my jsp and is making an ajax call. The jsp 'readFileNotings ' is getting returned properly in Firefox and Chrome,  but not in any version of IE.

```
             <s:iterator status="stat" value="alFileNoting" >
                   <s:if test="%{alFileNoting[#stat.index]=='File'}">
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                         <h6><span style="text-decoration:underline ;font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;color : #003366"><s:text  name="file.fileNo"></s:text><s:property value="alFileNoting[#stat.index+1].fileNo"/></span></h6>

                       </td>
                     </tr>          
                    </s:if>
                    <s:else> 
                    <tr><s:property value="stat.index"/></tr>            
                     <tr><td width=800 colspan="2" style="word-break:keep-all">
                     <div style="margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px; padding:0px 50px 0px 50px"><h5><%=i-- %>. <s:text name="file.notingBy"></s:text> 
                         <s:property
                            value="LyingWith" />, <s:property
                            value="CreatedDate" /></h5>
                          <%
                            out.println(request.getAttribute("FileDescription"));
                          %>

                          <s:if test="NotingAttachement1!=null || NotingAttachement2!=null || NotingAttachement3!=null">
                           <s:text name="attachement"></s:text>
                           </s:if>

                          <s:if test="NotingAttachement1!=null">
                            <s:a theme="simple" href="javascript:OpenAttachment('%{NotingAttachementId1}')">
                                <s:property value="NotingAttachement1"/>    
                            </s:a>

                          </s:if>

                          <s:if test="NotingAttachement2!=null">
                            <s:a theme="simple" href="javascript:OpenAttachment('%{NotingAttachementId2}')">
                                <s:property value="NotingAttachement2"/>    
                            </s:a>
                          </s:if>

                          <s:if test="NotingAttachement3!=null">
                            <s:a theme="simple" href="javascript:OpenAttachment('%{NotingAttachementId3}')">
                                <s:property value="NotingAttachement3"/>    
                            </s:a>
                          </s:if>
                           <s:form name="verifySignature" action="verifySignatureFilesAction.action"  > 

                            <input  name="alFileNoting" id="alFileNoting"    value="<s:property value="alFileNoting" />"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="notingNo" id="n"    value="<s:property value="notingId" />"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="SignedSignatureText" value="<s:property value="signatureText"/>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="SignedChallangeRespose" value="<s:property value="challangeResponse"/>"/>
                            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="SignedNotingDescription" value="<s:property value="FileDescription"/>"/> -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="SignedSignFlag" value="<s:property value="signFlag"/>"/>

                            <input type="hidden" name="SignedSectionName" value="<s:property value="sectionName"/>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="SignedFileNo" value="<s:property value="FileNo"/>"/>
                            <%
                            if("Y".equals(request.getAttribute("signFlag").toString()))
                            {%>
                                <h5><s:text name="file.signedBy"/><s:property value="LyingWith"/> 
                         </h5>                      
                            <%} %>



                             <input type="button"  class="bt-login" value="<s:text name="file.verify"/>" onclick="javascript:verify(this.form)"> 
                            <img name="result"  src="images/doubt.gif"  height="25" width="25"  />

                        </s:form>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="8" class="bgboxwhite">
                     <td height="6"></td>
                    </tr>
                </s:else>
                </s:iterator>
```

I am getting only 1 row returned in IE and none of the attachment is getting opened. Please help

Comment: seems syntax error. Can you please cross check if there is no unbalanced tags.Have you closed div tag?

Comment: yes...I have closed all the tgs. And is opening well in Chrome and firefox

Comment: can you update the snippet with latest changes since in this i dont see closing div

Comment: This snippet is the complete one